# Declarative Rollup Summary - error

Tags: unit-test, roll-up-summary

I want to create a Declarative Rollup Summary , but I hit the following error :

```
dlrs_pse_AssignmentTest.testTrigger System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: 

FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION, Bill Rate is required: [pse__Bill_Rate__c] 
Class.dlrs.RollupService.testHandler: line 282, column 1 
Class.dlrs_pse_AssignmentTest.testTrigger: line 11, column 1
```

Scenarios is as follow :

- Parent object : pse__Milestone__c
- Child Object : pse__Assignment__c
- Relationship field : pse__Milestone__c
- Field to aggregate : Days_Active__c
- Aggregate result field : Days_Active_Roll_Up__c

Manage child trigger :

```
/** * Auto Generated and Deployed by the Declarative Lookup Rollup Summaries Tool package (dlrs) **/ 
trigger dlrs_pse_AssignmentTrigger on pse__Assignment__c (before delete, before insert, before update, after delete, after insert, after undelete, after update) { 
dlrs.RollupService.triggerHandler(pse__Assignment__c.SObjectType); }   

 

/** * Auto Generated and Deployed by the Declarative Lookup Rollup Summaries Tool package (dlrs) **/ 
@IsTest private class dlrs_pse_AssignmentTest { @IsTest private static void testTrigger() { 
// Force the dlrs_pse_AssignmentTrigger to be invoked, fails the test if org config or other Apex code prevents this. 
   dlrs.RollupService.testHandler(new pse__Assignment__c()); } }
```

What might be the issue? I have deactivated the validation rule but still have this error.

Comment: Is `Bill Rate is required: [pse__Bill_Rate__c]` a required field in the schema for whatever object it is on?  That is, this may not be a Validation Rule - it may be a Required= checkbox. Also, check all objects in the DLRS rollup chain for this field in case it is included on more than one object

Answer (score 1):

The field might be set to be required at the object level. You can modify the test created to include values for the `pse__Assignment__c` object that is inserted in the test.

To do this, you should build the rollup in a sandbox first. Then you can edit the `dlrs_pse_AssignmentTest` class and modify the line

```
dlrs.RollupService.testHandler(new pse__Assignment__c()); } }
```

to be something like

```
dlrs.RollupService.testHandler(new pse__Assignment__c(pse__Bill_Rate__c = 1)); } }
```

Once the test passes in the sandbox, then you can deploy using a change set or other tools.

See https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries/wiki/Challenges-with-Code-Coverage for more information.

Comment: Daniel, thank you so much. I tried to complete the test class but I have the following error : * classes/dlrs_pse_AssignmentTest.cls (Line: 10: Column:32) : Type requires name=value pair construction: pse__Assignment__c*

Comment: I'd need to see the code you are using. Also, I'm making an assumption on the field type that it is a number.

Comment: I added bellow statement on the DRLS in my test class. Because I want to be applied for all the assignments with Bill rate higher than 0 . Bill rate is a currency field. 
dlrs.RollupService.testHandler(new pse__Assignment__c(pse__Bill_Rate__c > 0));

Comment: You can't do that. You are just creating a sample pse__Assignment__c record for the tests to run on. It needs to be something like `pse__Bill_Rate__c = 0`